# Is it possible use Cocos2d-x in web?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x game (written in C++) and I need to integrate it with social networking websites such as Facebook so that the user can play the game in the browser. Is it possible? If so how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check Cocos2d-html5 [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5).

It's a JavaScript engine based on Cocos2d-x

Another way be that you modify your code to work with WebGL instead of cocos2d-x; however that requires much more effort.
I hope my answer helps. :)

Comment: Cocos2d-JS allow use once written code (javascript) for multiple platforms. But Cocos2d-x code (C/C++) can not be used in web. So I need modify my code.

Comment: Yes, you need to adapt from C/C++ to JavaScript. And btw, it would be a good idea to add some introduction to your professional profile. :)